# Convert navbar for desktop to responsive menu bar for mobile using HTML5/CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be the best way to convert the following navbar I have to a mobile friendly version using HTML5/CSS3?

eg from...

[image]

to...

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Page 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```
#nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
#nav > ul > li a {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 2.3em 0.5em 1.35em 0.5em;
}
#nav > ul > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li.current {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#nav > ul > li.present {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#nav > ul > li.present:before {
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    width: 0.75em;
    height: 0.75em;
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.5em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -0.375em;
    background-color: #37c0fb;
}
#nav > ul > li.present a {
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li.active.present:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
#nav {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.75em;
    background-color: #37c0fb;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5evbpg4j/1/

Comment: One of the best option to use HTML framework like Bootstrap.

Comment: @Manwal - thanks for the response. Is it possible to do it without Bootstrap? I have already committed to this approach, but will keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: You can achieve this by [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). This way you can define css for different different screen.

Comment: media queries will be good and a nice learning curve if you wish else bootstrap is an option like mentioned about; Using media queries to show and hide dom elements for the correct displayed is one of my favorites

Comment: @Manwal the best approach to creating a simple navigation is to use an _entire_ CSS framework? That's not how you learn.

Comment: @SexyTurnip thats what i have suggested earlier to OP. But he don't want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of simple responsive navigation using html5/css3/jquery

Check on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w432pmyy/1/

```js
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$("#nav-toggle").click(function () {
    $("#nav ul").slideToggle();
    $("#nav ul").toggleClass("open");
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth > 767) {
        if ($("#nav ul").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#nav ul").css("display","block");
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#nav ul").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

```css
#nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
    display:block
}
#nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
#nav > ul > li a {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    padding:1.05em 0.5em;
}
#nav > ul > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li.current {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#nav > ul > li.present {
    font-weight: 600;
}
#nav > ul > li.present:before {
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    width: 0.75em;
    height: 0.75em;
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.5em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -0.375em;
    background-color: #37c0fb;
}
#nav > ul > li.present a {
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li.active.present:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
#nav {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.75em;
    background-color: #37c0fb;
}
#nav-toggle {
    display:none;
    background-color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-toggle > a {
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    width: 26px;
}
#nav-toggle > a > span {
    width:26px;
    height:2px;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:block;
}
#nav-toggle > a > span + span {
    margin-top:4px;
}
.menu-caption {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    #nav-toggle {
        display:block;
    }
    #nav > ul {
        display:none;
    }
    #nav > ul > li {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-toggle"> <a href="#">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </a>

    <div class="menu-caption">Menu</div>
</div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>    <a href="#">Page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">Page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">Page 3</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">Page 4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    </div
```

Comment: this was helpful for me (+1), while in media mode (<767 pixels) is there an easy way to fold back the menu to the hamburger symbol  if there's a press somewhere outside of the menu? At the moment the behavior is that the full block remains  in the screen after a press out of it, a better behavior will be to fold it after a menu item was selected.